# Web-scraping in IBM Watson Studio Jupyter Notebook using BeautifulSoup not working

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, ibm-watson

I'm looking to **scrape** data in an IBM Watson Studio Jupyter Notebook from this search result page:

`https://www.aspc.co.uk/search/?PrimaryPropertyType=Rent&SortBy=PublishedDesc&LastUpdated=AddedAnytime&SearchTerm=&PropertyType=Residential&PriceMin=&PriceMax=&Bathrooms=&OrMoreBathrooms=true&Bedrooms=&OrMoreBedrooms=true&HasCentralHeating=false&HasGarage=false&HasDoubleGarage=false&HasGarden=false&IsNewBuild=false&IsDevelopment=false&IsParkingAvailable=false&IsPartExchangeConsidered=false&PublicRooms=&OrMorePublicRooms=true&IsHmoLicense=false&IsAllowPets=false&IsAllowSmoking=false&IsFullyFurnished=false&IsPartFurnished=false&IsUnfurnished=false&ExcludeUnderOffer=false&IncludeClosedProperties=true&ClosedDatesSearch=14&MapSearchType=EDITED&ResultView=LIST&ResultMode=NONE&AreaZoom=13&AreaCenter[lat]=57.14955426557916&AreaCenter[lng]=-2.0927401123046785&EditedZoom=13&EditedCenter[lat]=57.14955426557916&EditedCenter[lng]=-2.0927401123046785`

I've tried BeautifulSoup and attempted Selenium (full disclosure: I am a beginner) over multiple variations of codes. I've gone over dozens of questions on Stack Overflow, Medium articles, etc and I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.

The latest one I'm doing is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

properties_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'information-card property-card  col  ')
print(type(properties_containers))
print(len(properties_containers))
```

This returns 0.

```
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
0
```

Can someone please guide me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong/ missing?

Answer (score 0):

The data you see is loaded via JavaScript. BeautifulSoup cannot execute it, but you can use `requests` module to load the data from their API.

For example:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.aspc.co.uk/search/?PrimaryPropertyType=Rent&SortBy=PublishedDesc&LastUpdated=AddedAnytime&SearchTerm=&PropertyType=Residential&PriceMin=&PriceMax=&Bathrooms=&OrMoreBathrooms=true&Bedrooms=&OrMoreBedrooms=true&HasCentralHeating=false&HasGarage=false&HasDoubleGarage=false&HasGarden=false&IsNewBuild=false&IsDevelopment=false&IsParkingAvailable=false&IsPartExchangeConsidered=false&PublicRooms=&OrMorePublicRooms=true&IsHmoLicense=false&IsAllowPets=false&IsAllowSmoking=false&IsFullyFurnished=false&IsPartFurnished=false&IsUnfurnished=false&ExcludeUnderOffer=false&IncludeClosedProperties=true&ClosedDatesSearch=14&MapSearchType=EDITED&ResultView=LIST&ResultMode=NONE&AreaZoom=13&AreaCenter[lat]=57.14955426557916&AreaCenter[lng]=-2.0927401123046785&EditedZoom=13&EditedCenter[lat]=57.14955426557916&EditedCenter[lng]=-2.0927401123046785'
api_url = 'https://api.aspc.co.uk/Property/GetProperties?{}&Sort=PublishedDesc&Page=1&PageSize=12'

params = url.split('?')[-1]
data = requests.get(api_url.format(params)).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))                     # <-- uncomment this to see all data received from server

# print some data to screen:
for property_ in data:
    print(property_['Location']['AddressLine1'])
    print(property_['CategorisationDescription'])
    print('Bedrooms:', property_["Bedrooms"])           # <-- print number of Bedrooms
    print('Bathrooms:', property_["Bathrooms"])         # <-- print number of Bathrooms
    print('PublicRooms:', property_["PublicRooms"])     # <-- print number of PublicRooms
    # .. etc.
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
44 Roslin Place
Fully furnished 2 Bdrm 1st flr Flat. Hall. Lounge. Dining kitch. 2 Bdrms. Bathrm (CT band - C). Deposit 1 months rent. Parking. No pets. No smokers. Rent £550 p.m Entry by arr. Viewing contact solicitors. Landlord reg: 871287/100/26061. (EPC band - B).
Bedrooms: 2
Bathrooms: 1
PublicRooms: 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Second Floor Left,  173 Victoria Road
Unfurnished 1 Bdrm 2nd flr Flat. Hall. Lounge. Dining kitch. Bdrm. Bathrm (CT Band - A). Deposit 1 months rent. No pets. No smokers. Rent £375 p.m Immed entry. Viewing contact solicitors. Landlord reg: 1261711/100/09072. (EPC band - D).
Bedrooms: 1
Bathrooms: 1
PublicRooms: 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
102 Bedford Road
Fully furnished 3 Bdrm 1st flr Flat. Hall. Lounge. Kitch. 3 Bdrms. Bathrm (CT band - B). Deposit 1 months rent. Garden. HMO License. No pets. No smokers. Rent £750 p.m Entry by arr. Viewing contact solicitors. Landlord reg: 49171/100/27130. (EPC band - D).
Bedrooms: 3
Bathrooms: 1
PublicRooms: 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```

Comment: that's very useful but I need part of the information from the page itself: full address (including postcode), no of lounges, bathrooms and square footage. How can I extract that? Thank you

Comment: @Alex03 The data is **not** inside the page, the page loads the data from remote API. If you uncomment `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))` you will see all data that is received from the server. I updated my example.